# get current admin's websites numbers

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento and was trying to figure out if there is a way to find out the number of websites the current administrator is managing ?

Please suggest/advice.

Comment: "number of sites managed" is a terrible way to decide who should get access to what. You really need to re-think your strategy. Get a proper access list, or don't bother with any access control at all.

Comment: What does your access list structure look like?

Comment: I want to customize customer information page view, both admins can get to this page, but I want different view for each admin, how can I distinguish between the two admins??

Comment: thanx for responding :)